# Play Framework [play-mailer]: how to ensure each receiver sees only his or her email address in the TO field

Tags: plugins, playframework, mailer

Here below is the code to send an email with `play-mailer`:

```
import play.api.libs.mailer._
...

val email = Email(
  "My Subject",
  "Me <j3d@domain.com>",
  Seq("john@domain.com", "joe@domain.com", "jack@domain.com"),
  bodyText = Some("Some text..."),
  bodyHtml = Some("<p>Some text...</p>")
)
MailerPlugin.send(email)
```

The problem is that receivers see all the recipients the email was sent to. Of course, an option could be to invoke `MailerPlugin.send` for every single recipient... but I'm wondering if there is a better way to ensure each receiver sees only his or her email address in the `to` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the best solution will be using hidden recepient which aka `BCC`. Emailer plugin has method [addBcc(String address)](https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer/blob/master/src/main/java/play/libs/mailer/Email.java#L80):

```
 public void addBcc(String address) {
    this.bcc.add(address);
  }
```

Regards!